# Open cart extension Compatibility

Tags: php, opencart

I have Open Cart version 1.4.8 and trying to install Extension that is compatible with 1.4.9.3

Should it actually work when I install this module still?

Comment: i have written a few opencart extensions and there are very few changes between 1.4.8 and 1.4.9, 1.5 is a different story however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most 1.4.8 extensions will be compatible with 1.4.9.x - There were only minor changes between the versions, so you should be able to make any required changes with little effort

You should also check with the developer of the module if they have a separate 1.4.9.X version, as they might, and most developers will actually give you an upgrade at no extra cost too

Of course, 1.4.8 was before the vQmod's started to be generated, so if it's an extension where you have to make lots of file edits, it might be a little outdated, but as I say it shouldn't be too far out of date. You could always get in touch with a developer on the opencart commercial forum to upgrade it, or if this is a free extension, you could post it in the free extension area and request help off anyone that can for upgrading it